# How can I create a module/extension base system in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I wrote a system using [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) which multiple modules/package capability. All of the modules will be located in a folder called `modules`.

To get started, I wrote a small package which is located in a folder called `modules/Mikea/Surveys`. The folder `Mikea` is the vendor's name and `Surveys` is the module/package name. Each package must have it's own `composer.json` file which allows the developer to configure each package with it's own composer configs.

The idea here is to have one Laravel installation that supports extension to allow any developer to contribute into my main "system."

Here is how my `modules` folder looks like

```
modules
modules/Mikea
modules/Mikea/Surveys
modules/Mikea/Surveys/database
modules/Mikea/Surveys/resources
modules/Mikea/Surveys/composer.json
modules/Mikea/Surveys/routes.php

modules/Mikea/Surveys/src
modules/Mikea/Surveys/src/Controllers
modules/Mikea/Surveys/src/Jobs
modules/Mikea/Surveys/src/Models
modules/Mikea/Surveys/src/....
```

In my main `composer.json` file I am using "path" type in the repositories section like you see in the following composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.x-dev",
        "mikea/surveys": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": " ~3.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "modules/mikea/Surveys"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

In `modules/Mikea/Surveys` I have another `composer.json` file that allows me to configure each package separately like, package version, license, author....

Here is a copy of my second composer.json file "composer.json for my extension"

```
{
    "name": "mikea/surveys",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "0.1.4",
    "description": "Survey System",
    "keywords": ["Mike A", "Surveys"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mike A",
            "email": "mikea@example.com"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/migrations",
            "database/seeds"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "mikea\\Surveys\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Everything works fine right now. All I have to do is execute `composer update` from the command line. It will simply copy the files from `\modules\Mikea\Surveys` into  `\vendor\mikea\Surveys`

Then I can publish my views using the command line.

The problem that I am facing is that every time I make a change to the files in `modules/Mikea/Surveys` I will have to do the following 2 ugly steps to see my work in the browsers.

1. In my second `composer.json` file, I have to increase the value of the version number of my modules "basically trick composer to think there is a new version of the package"
2. run `composer update` to copy the files all over again from `\modules\Mikea\Surveys` into  `\vendor\mikea\Surveys`

This is obviously too much work and no one want to do this!

How can I do to tell composer to auto load the files from `modules/Mikea/Surveys` while I am in development mode? So instead keep changing/updating I would keep working from the `\modules\Mikea\Surveys` folder until I am ready to release a new release of my package. Once ready, I would create a new version and run `composer update` to get the latest available version.

I am open to better ideas on how to develop such a system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespaces for all the modules in pst-4 object in the main composer.json file, same as you did for the mikea\surveys.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap/autoload.php bind the require to a variable as in:

```
$autoload = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then:

```
$autoload->addPsr4($namespace, $path);
```

This will register your namespaces with the composer autoloader without adding anything to your composer.json. You can also create a second json alongside your composer.json that will autoload the namespaces and a service provider in your laravel application that will autoload the serviceproviders of enabled packages.